# Core data without the persistence

Tags: ios, core-data

Would there ever be a case for using Core data as the object model within an application, even though persistence isn't required? If I had a fairly complex Object graph with many relations, I like the idea of Core Data and its KVO properties. Instead of actually creating Classes of the Model I need, I could subclass NSManagedObject and let core data handle all the updating and fetching. With my current application I am left with a sort of mess of callback functions and Object repository classes that deal with the model and the viewControllers that are notified when things get changed.. Core Data seems much cleaner to me in that respect.

Comment: Why would you not be persisting if it's a complex graph that has taken time / effort to create?

Comment: I could persist, but the data always needs to be refreshed from a server on startup anyway.. any data before that point is out of date and cant be displayed to the user.

Comment: even if they're offline ? persistence is also about memory utilisation...